# Binding problem which drives me crazy

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, combobox

I (and other programmers from another forum) have been trying to solve a binding problem for a few days. No one could help... Will anyone here be able to help me ? Apparently, the problem seems quite simple but when you dive in it, trust me, you burn some neurons...
Here it is : I've created a test project which reproduces the problem. Download it from [here](http://cjoint.com/?kcu641uNgY).
Run the project and :

- select a member from the listbox
- type    in a ZIP code in the textbox
  (these    are french ZIP, from 01000
  to 98000)
- select a city in the combobox
- select another member and do the same
  (with    a different ZIP code) then
  select    back the previous member
  and    re-select the other one => see
  how    the member.Ville.ID property
  is lost    and so how the
  SelectedItem in the    combobox is
  lost as well.

Why the hell does it do that ?
How to solve this ?

P.S : sorry for the french in the classes' properties and elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Something is setting that value back.  I haven't investigated too much, but I put a binding diagnostic (here's how to do this yourself: [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52)) on your binding and got this:

```
Update - got raw value '9800'
Update - using final value '9800'
SetValue at level 1 to Ville (hash=15263193) using RuntimePropertyInfo(CodePostal): '9700'
Got PropertyChanged event from Ville (hash=15263193)
Update - got raw value '97001'
Update - using final value '97001'
SetValue at level 1 to Ville (hash=15263193) using RuntimePropertyInfo(CodePostal): '97001'
Got PropertyChanged event from Ville (hash=15263193)
Update - got raw value '01000'
Update - using final value '01000'
SetValue at level 1 to Ville (hash=15263193) using RuntimePropertyInfo(CodePostal): '01000'
Got PropertyChanged event from Ville (hash=15263193)
```

Notice that as soon as I hit the last "1" in 97001, a PropertyChanged notification was raised resetting it back to 01000, so something was setting it back to that.

I put in a conditional breakpoint in the Set method of your Code for "value.Equals("01000")" and got the stack trace for when that occured:

```
TestMembre.exe!TestMembre.Ville.set_CodePostal(String value = "01000") Line 47  Basic
TestMembre.exe!TestMembre.Window1.txtCodePostal_TextChanged(Object sender = {System.Windows.Controls.TextBox}, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs})
```

So what you should be noticing here is that the TextChanged event of the txtCodePostal has some code that is setting that value:

```
Else
   'If the zip code doesn't exist, it is set to one that does
   txtCodePostal.Text = "01000"
```

I don't know exactly how your logic *should* work, but that line of code right there is always firing and resetting your value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK. Thanks, I think your message will do help me a lot ! I'll check my code tomorrow... See you

Answer (score 0):

Your message helped me in the way that I could debug the Binding, thanks to your link.
Notice that, for me, the `txtCodePostal.Text = "01000"` never happened, cause I always type in a right ZIP code. This is meant to happen only if the user type in a ZIP code that doesn't exist. Though, I've used the Trace Sources from Bea Stollnitz web site to debug my binding. I've saved it to [this txt file](http://cjoint.com/?kdmBagmiBp). There are some errors that occur when the SelectionChanged from the listbox happens. I've not understood all stuff yet, but I'm trying... If you could have a look at this file, it'd be pretty kind...